# Get client computer name on SharePoint using JavaScript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, client

Any idea how to get the client computer name or the client computer details within any SharePoint Site collection

Comment: You can't. Or you can if the user uses IE and it still doesn't work all the time. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/922529/286244

Comment: We can long time i have seen the script and i forgot now :(, SharePoint script has the capacity

Answer (score -1):

I got the reference of this

## [STACKOVERFLOW LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser/922529#922529)

You can do it with IE 'sometimes' as I have done this for an internal application on an intranet which is IE only. Try the following:

```
function GetComputerName() {
    try {
        var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
        // Show a pop up if it works
        alert(network.computerName);
    }
    catch (e) { }
}
```

It may or may not require some specific security setting setup in IE as well to allow the browser to access the ActiveX object.

Here is a link to some more info on WScript: [Link](http://www.pctools.com/guides/scripting/id/3/?act=reference)

Comment: This answer is an exact copy of answer posted at StackOverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/a/922529/3615197. Please quote if you are referencing answer from another user. Also Benny Skogberg has already provided this link in previous comments.

Comment: Now it's okay @Yayati? I've copied the answer because if that thread will destroyed in future then this answer will be helpful.